# How to create a glitch effect

Tags: effects

In many films(especially trailers) we can see some kind of glitch effects. Recently I found one more here:

Video on FB: [link](https://www.facebook.com/CKibeofficial/videos/1331715273506346/).

I want to try to create one by myself but cant find any useful info. How and where is it possible to make? I would be pleased to see some links and guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K guys. Found this guide to make glitch effect after all:

Thx guys for answering, you made my day :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several effects like this available today. If you're using Final Cut Pro X or Motion, you can use the [BadTV](http://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.3/#/motn169fdc8c) filter.

There are also 3rd party filters for a variety of platforms including [DigiEffects' Damage](http://www.digieffects.com/products/damage/) filters.

You could probably make your own by copying your input video, applying noise, maybe offsetting it, and then masking parts of the result to mix with the original.

Comment: Thx, but I`m on windows :/ Is there any analogy for windows?

Comment: I think the DigiEffects works with After Effects and Premiere on Windows. If you want to do it by hand, I would think AE and Premiere have the pieces you need - noise, transformations, etc.

Comment: oh, thx. I don't think I can do that myself, thats why I asked here how to do that :) I'll look that filter as soon as I can, thx  ones more.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into http://www.MotionVFX.com .. they have glitch effects as plugins which they sell. 
For most software and all are quite good customizable.

Comment: Thx, but looks like the only useful effect mGlitch is only available for Mac :(